# .getElementsAtEventForMode using chart id in chart.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, onclick, chart.js

I'm trying to make a onClick handler function in chart.js which returns the label of the bar clicked in. I'm aware of the funciton `.getElementsAtEventForMode` but it requires for you to have the chart's name. This is a problem because I'm using components and am not calling the chart directly so all the graphs have the same name. I was wandering if there was a way to call this function using perhaps the component's vue.js id.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: it does not require the name, it requires the reference to that chart instance. So as long as you can access the chart reference in your vue component you can call the function on it

Comment: "it requires for you to have the chart's name" - does it? As I see, it requires to have a reference to chart object. And that's what you should have, whether you use components or not. Keep a reference to it in order to access it